# Creating statements using symbols

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Are these statements correct? And can anyone help me figure out letter c?

Let h = Joe is healthy, w = Joe is wealthy, s = Joe is wise.

a. Joe is healthy and wealthy but not wise.

Answer: (h∧w) ∧ ~ s

b. Joe is not wealthy but he is healthy and wise.

Answer: ~w ∧ (h∧s)

c. Joe is neither healthy, wealthy, nor wise.

Answer: Cant figure out help please?

d. Joe is neither wealthy, nor wise, but he is healthy.

Answer: (~w∧~s) ∧ h

e. Joe is wealthy, but he is not both healthy and wise.

Answer: w ∧ ~(h∧s)

Comment: The last one is healthy and wise, h and s and not w and s.

Comment: Ya, looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like c. is $ \sim \! h\, \wedge \sim \! w\ \wedge \sim \! s$. He is none of the above. The rest of your statements look fine.